# How to get the certificate password from a self signed certificate

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I want to aquire a token from an Azure app registration with a certificate.
I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) and generated a self signed certificate with Powershell. I also imported the public key into the portal.
But if I want to access the app via .NET, I need to provide the following MSAL configuration:

[image]

The CertificateFileContents is just the public key I exported from the certgmgr. But what should I put as the CertificatePass? Is this a hash? Or a private key? I could not find anything in the docs and also the link above does not give me any advice...

Also I do not really understand why the private key is not imported to the portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the CertificatePass was the password for the certificate itself.
The Azure Portal itself only holds the public key.
The client application needs to provide the whole certificate with private and public key.
If you export a private/public key from certificate manager in Windows 10, you will not be able to directly export this as base64, but you can create a pfx file.
Those files can later be encoded to Base64 with a tool of your choice. For example [this](https://www.browserling.com/tools/file-to-base64).
The password for your certificate has to be the CertificatePass, the FileContents are the Base64 public and private key, but decrypted with the password.

This is of course only an approach for testing purpose. In a production environment you would rather use key vault or something similar to not have any secrets in your appsettings.json.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, CertificatePass should be required when you export a private key.

This document has such content before:

> Export the private key, specify a password for the cert file, and
>   export to a file.

But now it only tells you to export a public key. You can see details from [this issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/49864).

So based on the [SharePoint document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread), if you are reading a PFX file from your local machine, I think you should use private key with a password.

Comment: Exactly this issue is confusing me. Do I need a private key at all to secure my app registration? Or is the public key enough? Why is only a public key needed? And even if I export a private key, I get only a binary file what I cannot use as an input in my config file from above. For me the whole private/public key thing with app registrations is not documented enough... I understand the concept for SSL certificates and signing/verifying, but how it works with App registrations I do not understand...

Comment: @DavidElsner In theory, both public and private keys should be feasible. But I don't know about your how your configuration file is implemented. Is it a sample code from GitHub?

Comment: From the docs. In the end I create a certificate from .NET. The constructor gets the bytes from the base64 and the certificate password like: _certificate = new X509Certificate2(certBytes, options.CertificatePass);

Comment: @DavidElsner So this issue is resolved right? You could add an answer and marked it as answered. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.